# How to resolve this promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, noty

I'm applying this library which is called noty and I want to resolve this promise. Here is the code.

```
    var bouncejsClose = function (promise) {
    var n = this;
    new Bounce()
        .translate({
            from: { x: 0, y: 0 }, to: { x: 450, y: 0 },
            easing: 'bounce',
            duration: 500,
            bounces: 4,
            stiffness: 1
        })
        .applyTo(n.barDom, {
            onComplete: function () {
                promise(function (resolve) {
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: could you give me the package link?

Comment: Sure. Here is the link https://ned.im/noty/#/animations

Answer (score 1):

You can't resolve a `Promise` from `outside` of its declaration, what you need to do is:

```
var bouncejsClosePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var n = this;
  new Bounce()
    .translate({
      from: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      to: { x: 450, y: 0 },
      easing: "bounce",
      duration: 500,
      bounces: 4,
      stiffness: 1
    })
    .applyTo(n.barDom, {
      onComplete: function () {
        //now you can resolve here
        resolve(/** with any value you want to get when calling .then method */)
      }
    });
});

bouncejsClosePromise.then((/** if you pass value to the resolve callback, you can get it here */) => {
  //your promise successfully resolved
}).catch(() => {
  //or in case you used reject in your promise, you can handle it here
})
```